# Boost Process 1.71 does not look in environment path anymore

Tags: c++, boost, boost-process

I have been using boost 1.65, did not change the code, updated boost to version 1.71 and now suddenly `boost::process::child("command-in-path")` does not inherit the environment of the executing process. How can I recover the behavior, is it possible without parsing the command every time to find the executable in path?

Comment: I wonder why people downvoted your post. Perhaps it is because of a lack of code. You could easily have added ~3 surrounding lines of code to make the sample self-contained, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked whether the behaviour actually changed, but I know there's a way to explicitly allow Boost to search the path:

> Keep in mind that searching the path can easily be a security issue because it can be compromised, or attackers can leverage knowledge of the path setting to intercept executables. This is why you'd expect `search_path` to be OFF by default (except for the `system` interface, which is traditionally insecure)

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WRZ6cGc39eyaY0Jj)**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

int main() {
    namespace bp = boost::process;

    bp::child c(
        bp::search_path("date"),
        std::vector<std::string> { "+%s" });
    c.wait();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the flaws explanation, however, I do not think it is a danger in my application. So if my command consists of more than just executable, i.e. executable and several arguments. I have to break it into tokens, no other way. Cause in 1.65 I could just pass one string.